# Hardware Accelerated does not work properly

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, html5-canvas

If I keep `android:hardwareAccelerated="false` the video doesn't run on foreground(it runs in background). And If I keep `android:hardwareAccelerated="true` mqrquee text and other static images are flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my problem. I used   `webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)`
in the webView.